# CSS location content/option dropdownlist

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Very simple question but I've been googling for hours and haven't found anything

How can i style the content/option/popup of a dropdownlist on the right side of the 'open button' like in this image/screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/joqj00ahjrwqs0p/Capture.PNG?dl=0 ?

Comment: what style aspects do you wanna add?

Comment: basically the list with <option>'s need to open on the right side of the arrow that opens the list (see dropbox image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot style it. You need to create a replacement element. Some browser elements can not be changed, or almost not be changed, with regard to their styling. They are so-called "native" (referring to the operating system) controls.

Check here for some jQuery based replacements which you can style whatever way you like:

http://jquery-plugins.net/fancyselect-jquery-plugin-for-custom-select-box

Comment: Thx! I'm going to try this, will keep you posted

Comment: So you might want to mark this as the answer that solved your problem?